# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError - Caused by having a function with parameter returning array for *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

Each row in my table has an `itemId`.  I customized a column to have the following below...

```
<td>
...
<div *ngFor="let hour of calculateHours(itemId)">
<div class="amount" [ngStyle]="{'height': '5px', 'width': getWidth(hour)}"></div>
</div>
...
</td>
```

My issue is when I add more `hours` to `Item`, the data in my table doesn't refresh.

I know binding to a method in the template is bad, and will be called on every change detection, but I can't think of a good way to get the data displayed initially and have the data refreshed when `hours` changed. The only place I can get hours is where I have my `itemId` in each row.

So I guess `*ngFor="let hour of calculatedHours"` would work just perfectly, but I need my `itemId` to calculate...

Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: Need to see your ts code - its a timing issue, you're changing the data before angular has officially stopped synchronising it.

Comment: Please, provide live example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the function calculateHours directly on your page.  Better to have your code return a type Observable of hours.  You can subscribe in the code or better still if possible use an async pipe.

If you are able to return CalculateHours as an Observable of hours. ie type observable you can implement it as follows...

```
<div *ngFor="let hour of hours | async">
<div class="amount" [ngStyle]="{'height': '5px', 'width': hour}"></div>
</div>
```

And any changes to hours, would reflect on the page.